# shorten vectors by using certain means

Tags: r, vector

I have a simple question, but I can't find the right solution => I have a list (let's call it "list") consisting of about 2000 ordinary vectors (list[[1]],list[[2]], etc.). Each of those vectors contains 50399 numbers. Now what I want is to shorten each vector so that it consits of 840 numbers in the end.

So I want the first number to be the mean of the first 60 numbers of the original vector (mean(list[[i]][1:60])), the second number shall be the mean of the next 60 numbers etc. That should work 839 times (for 50399 numbers altogether). So the last number should be the mean of the last 59 (not 60) numbers of the original vector.

That should work for each veactor (list[[i]]) in "list"!

Do you guys have an idea how that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work it out like this:

```
set.seed(1)
(list <- replicate(3, sample(1:10, 10, T), simplify = FALSE))
# [[1]]
# [1]  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  3  2  7  4  8  5  8 10  4  8
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 10  3  7  2  3  4  1  4  9  4

n <- 5 # crunch vectors of 10 into 5 means
lapply(list, function(x) sapply(split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/(length(x)/n))), mean))
# [[1]]
# 1   2   3   4   5 
# 3.5 8.0 6.0 8.5 4.0 
# 
# [[2]]
# 1   2   3   4   5 
# 2.5 5.5 6.5 9.0 6.0 
# 
# [[3]]
# 1   2   3   4   5 
# 6.5 4.5 3.5 2.5 6.5
```

i.e., in your case:

```
list <- replicate(2000, sample(1:10, 50399, T), simplify = FALSE)
res <- lapply(list, function(x) sapply(split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/(length(x)/840))), mean))
sapply(res, length) # check
```

Comment: Probably could do it with a hack on `rollapply` too :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Hmm never used it, but sounds interesting.

Comment: Maybe like this `lapply(list, rollapply, mean, width=60, by=60, partial=TRUE)`.

Comment: Cool, one should add this as another answer.

Comment: @lukeA Or, you can add it to your answer.

Comment: @lukeA Thanks! Almost perfect! But I only need the numbers e.g. list[[1]][1] => 3.5 ... I don't really need the position :D So just the vector not a data  frame. How do you do that?

Comment: You can use `unname(list[[1]][1])` or - beforehand - `list <- lapply(list, function(x) unname(sapply(split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/(length(x)/n))), mean)))`.

Comment: @lukeA Thanks perfect! I didn't know the unname command :D cheers